# Using PySide.QtCore.Signal in threading.Thread object

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside

I am using something like this:

```
import threading
from PySide import QtCore

class Smt(threading.Thread):
    foo_signal = QtCore.Signal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self);
        while True:
            pass # and so..
```

Then I am starting it:

```
a = Smt()
a.foo_signal.connect(function)
a.start()
```

The output is:

```
AttributeError: 'PySide.QtCore.Signal' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

If I use `QtCore.QThread` instead of `threading.Thread` - it works great. But I don't want to use `QThread`.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signals require that the class which is using them be inherited from a QObject (Or any class which also inherits QObject). So you can either switch to using a QThread or also inherit from QObject and call `QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)` in your `__init__`